# How can I create a list with all the possible combinations of common letters between two strings?

Tags: python, string, list, set

I have tried using `set()`, as it will print only unique elements of both sets.
In my code, `common_letters` is the set of common letters from both strings.
I'm trying to print all the possible combinations of words which can be generated from the elements of `common_letters` and also trying to convert that word list into one where the first letter of each string is capitalized.

This is my code so far:

```
import itertools as itr

def listtostring(s):
    string =" "
    return (string.join(s))

str1=input("Enter 1st string:")
str2=input("Enter 2nd string:")
common_letters=set(set(str1) & set(str2))

for letter in common_letters:
    common_letters.add(letter)
print("list of common letters : ",common_letters)

mylist=list(itr.permutations(common_letters))

print("Words generated from common letters are : ",listtostring(mylist))
```

I am getting the following error however:

```
File "C:/Users/problem_1.py", line 18, in <module>
    print("Words generated from common letters are : ",listtostring(mylist))

File "C:/Users/problem_1.py", line 5, in listtostring
    return (string.join(s))

TypeError sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

The expected output should be all combinations of common letters forming words (as String type) with first letter in uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your `listtostring` function wrong, you should use that on every permutation created, not on the whole list of permutations. And you can use `capitalize()` to capitalize the first letters.

Here is the modified code, I removed your for loop as it wasn't doing anything:

```
import itertools as itr

def listtostring(s):
    string = ""
    return (string.join(s))

str1=input("Enter 1st string:")
str2=input("Enter 2nd string:")
common_letters=set(set(str1) & set(str2))
print("list of common letters : ",common_letters)

mylist=list(itr.permutations(common_letters))
finalList = [listtostring(x).capitalize() for x in mylist]

print("Words generated from common letters are : ", finalList)
```

You can change the last line to the following if you want it to all be one string:

```
print("Words generated from common letters are : ", " ".join(finalList))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping , but the output i wanted is in string type.all element of list finalList should be converted into string type, as it is showing type as <class 'list'>.

Comment: @SurendraSingh So, you want one long string, with all the words separated by a space? see my updated answer.

Comment: @SurendraSingh Please mark as solved if this solved your issue or let me know what the issue is.